# convert string in utf-8 format to unicode : Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a text file with lines like:

```
str = '0|Crazy Taxi\xe2\x84\xa2 City Rush^Truck Racing Super Gear^Candy Crush Soda Saga^Car Parking^BMX Kid^Hill Climb Racing^UNLimited Kareena Kapoor^3D Car Parking^Find My Android Phone!^Christmas Trains^Top Free Games^Telegram^Door Screen Lock^Adventure of Ted 2 - Free^Sonic Jump^'
```

I want to to remove "\xe2\x84\xa2" which i am able to do using the following code line:

```
print unicode(str,errors="ignore")

output = '0|Crazy Taxi City Rush^Truck Racing Super Gear^Candy Crush Soda Saga^Car Parking^BMX Kid^Hill Climb Racing^UNLimited Kareena Kapoor^3D Car Parking^Find My Android Phone!^Christmas Trains^Top Free Games^Telegram^Door Screen Lock^Adventure of Ted 2 - Free^Sonic Jump^'
```

But when I am running the same logic on complete files using below mentioned code:

```
with open('train_data_dump.txt', mode='r') as document:
    for line in document:
        print unicode(line,errors='ignore')
```

It is printing the line as it was before.

Feel free to ask If I am not clear enough in asking question and please help.

Comment: check the indentation.

Comment: That is posting mistake, I will edit that. Thanks

Comment: So the text file contains Python source code?

Comment: No Sir, It has text written after crwaling web pages seperated by "^".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a variable from a file it is as if you assigned a raw string - the backslash is considered a normal letter. You need to decode the escaped chars at first.

```
unicode(i.decode("string_escape"), errors="ignore")
```

[Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings)

Comment: will you please explain how it works internally and why it differs? Even i am trying to find a solution of this.

Comment: Thank you Sir, It has worked for me. I was also thinking alike and was using unicode(i.strip(), errors="ignore") at my end. But that was not working. Most probably because strip removes white spaces not the backslash.